# window.performance.timing undefined after waitForNavigation in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

This may fall under me just not understanding how things work.

I have the following code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '<value>';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '<value>';
const BUTTON_SELECTOR   = '<value>';
const ACCOUNT_SELECTOR  = '<value>';
const URL = '<value>';
const CREDS = require('./creds');

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];

  await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
  await page.goto(LOGIN_URL);
  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);
  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.password);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
    page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR),
  ]);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }),
    page.click(ACCOUNT_SELECTOR),
  ]);

  const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
    await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
    );
  console.log(performanceTiming);
  browser.close();
}

run();
```

What I *want* is to get the timing stats of the page that is loaded after the button is clicked.

I'm getting the following error:

```
(node:30097) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/aakins/Projects/performance/test.js:48:34)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Examining things, the window.performance.timing appears to be "undefined".

I'm obviously missing something, probably fundamental, but I've been unable to track it down.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Puppeteer are you using?

Comment: According to NPM, 1.2.0

Comment: `const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
  await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
);` looks perfectly fine for me. You should extend your example.

Comment: @everetts , edited the code above. It now shows everything except the values of the constants (which are just simple strings).

Comment: I hope you wrap everything inside `(async () => { ... })()`?

Comment: @Everettss - everything is in a function. I've updated it again, everything is there now.